# Why illegal structure operation in const pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Why do I have to add `&` in `cout` clause while using `const` pointer. I'm in the code below. And if I don't add `&` clause it says `illegal structure operation`.

```
int Marks [10]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
// Create a constant pointer to Marks array
const int* pMarks = Marks;
for (int i = 0, bytes = 0; i < 10; ++i, bytes += 4)
{
  cout <<  "Element " << i << ": " << pMarks <<" + ";
  cout <<  bytes << " bytes" << " = " << (pMarks + i) << endl; // that & is required before (pMarks + i)
}
```

I want my **output** would be something like this:
stdout:
**Element 0: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 0 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c0

Element 1: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 4 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c4

Element 2: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 8 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c8

Element 3: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 12 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6cc

Element 4: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 16 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d0

Element 5: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 20 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d4

Element 6: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 24 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d8

Element 7: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 28 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6dc

Element 8: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 32 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6e0**

Comment: Where is this `&` you mention?

Comment: are you trying to see an int composing bytes? or are you trying to see the values from the vector using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Note that `// Create a constant pointer to Marks array` is incorrect, you create a pointer to the `Marks` array which you can't use to modify the contents of the array. The pointer is not constant, that would be `int * const pMarks = Marks;`

Comment: This one is working for me, maybe you you mean *pMarks in the first cout.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
cout <<  bytes << " bytes" << " = " <<*(pMarks + i) << endl;
```

Otherwise you would be passing the address from `pMarks + i`.

Comment: @neagoegab is this modifier for cout?? But thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is working, but i want my output would be something like this:
stdout:
Element 0: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 0 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c0
Element 1: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 4 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c4
Element 2: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 8 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6c8
Element 3: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 12 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6cc
Element 4: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 16 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d0
Element 5: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 20 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d4
Element 6: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 24 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6d8
Element 7: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 28 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6dc
Element 8: 0x7fff1d26d6c0 + 32 bytes = 0x7fff1d26d6e0